# Change column spacing for specific columns in tikz graph

Tags: tikz-pgf, spacing

## The context

Consider this simple `tikz` graph

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary[positioning]

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[auto, node distance=1cm and 4cm]

\node[circle, draw] (1) {1};
\node[circle, draw] (2) [above right=of 1] {2};
\node[circle, draw] (3) [below right=of 1] {3};
\node[circle, draw] (4) [below left=of 3] {4};
\node[circle, draw] (5) [below right=of 4] {5};
\node[circle, draw] (6) [right=of 3] {6};
\node[circle, draw] (7) [right=of 6] {7};

\draw (1) to node {} (2)
      (1) to node {} (3)
      (1) to node {} (5)
      (4) to node {} (2)
      (4) to node {} (3)
      (4) to node {} (5)
      (2) to node {} (6)
      (3) to node {} (6)
      (5) to node {} (6)
      (6) to node {} (7);

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

## The question

Because `node distance=1cm and 4cm` is setting the spacing between all columns to `4cm`. I would like to change the column spacing where the nodes `6` and `7` are to `2cm` without changing the spacing between the other columns.

Comment: Change `\node[circle, draw] (7) [right=of 6] {7};` to `\node[circle, draw] (7) [right=2cm of 6] {7};`. See specific documentation in [`pgf` manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/base/doc/pgfmanual.pdf), section 17.5.3, the documentation of option `/tikz/above=<specification>`, second point.

Comment: In addition, use `\usetikzlibrary{positioning}` with curly brackets. You could also use a `matrix of nodes` to get this output, in which case you can modify the `column sep` for a specific column. In the case at hand, this does not bring any simplification, but if you have several nodes in that column, it does.

Answer (score 2):

This is just an off-topic comment, the correct answer is contained in [muzimuzhi's comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/548306/change-column-spacing-for-specific-columns#comment1384932_548306). You could use a `matrix of nodes` and set the `column sep` and `row sep` to fit your requirements. `tikz-cd` can make it particularly simple to punch in such matrices.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzcd}[column sep=6em,/tikz/column 3/.style={column sep=3em},
    cells={nodes={circle,draw}},arrows=dash]
 & 2\\
 1\arrow[ur]\arrow[dr]\arrow[dddr]\\
 & 3 & 6 \arrow[uul]\arrow[l]\arrow[ddl]\arrow[r]& 7\\
 4\arrow[uuur]\arrow[ur]\arrow[dr]\\
 & 5\\
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

[image]